# How can I control access to group-private content based on organic groups roles?

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups

I would like my groups to be able to create content that is not only private to a group, but also private to certain roles within the group. For example, a post that is only accessible by members of Group A that also have the "officer" role.

Ideally, I'd be able to make the roles group-specific because different groups should be able to create and assign roles to their members.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Additional info: I'm using Organic Groups version 7.x-1.3.

Answer (score 1):

I needed somewhat similar functionality for a drupal 6 site and gave up on using OG for this.
Instead I made a vocabulary that defined my groups and used tac_lite for setting access.
The setup is being ported to drupal 7 right now, and I haven't had any problems implementing the same functionality in d7 so far. 
Maybe tac_lite is a solution for you? http://drupal.org/project/tac_lite

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, which would twist your idea but still offer the same functionality would be http://drupal.org/project/og_subgroups (still in beta for D7 unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

[OG User Roles](http://drupal.org/project/og_user_roles) allows group administrators of organic groups to grant additional user roles to individual members of a certain group.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no version for Drupal 7. As far as I know, the module's functionality has been rolled into OG 7, but the roles I can grant still don't allow me to restrict _view_ permissions of a particular post to certain roles.

Answer (score 0):

To allow permissions and roles to be changeable for groups, you need to add that feature to the 'group entity' This can be achieved by using this example link. **http://yourwebsite/admin/config/group/fields**.

http://vimeo.com/34032652